# postgresql sort by specific algorithm

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with transactions that looks like this

```sql
create table temp.bt(id serial, transaction_date date,amount numeric, balance numeric);
insert into temp.bt (transaction_date, amount,balance) values
('2020-06-02',-310.44,46431.95),
('2020-05-29',  -1.25,  45743.62),
('2020-06-02',  -152.48,    46742.39),
('2020-05-29',  -2.00,  45744.87),
('2020-05-29',  3125.00,    47013.17),
('2020-06-02',  1151.25,    46894.87),
('2020-05-29',  -1266.30,   45746.87),
('2020-05-28',  158.48, 43888.17);
```

The order of rows is wrong:

```sql
id|transaction_date|amount  |balance |
--|----------------|--------|--------|
 9|      2020-06-02| -310.44|46431.95|
10|      2020-05-29|   -1.25|45743.62|
11|      2020-06-02| -152.48|46742.39|
12|      2020-05-29|   -2.00|45744.87|
13|      2020-05-29| 3125.00|47013.17|
14|      2020-06-02| 1151.25|46894.87|
15|      2020-05-29|-1266.30|45746.87|
16|      2020-05-28|  158.48|43888.17|
```

rows must be ordered not by `transaction_date` but by some algorithm:
calculating `balance - amount` in each row, and previous row's "balance" column must be equal to this calculated row's value.

I need something like this:

```sql
transaction_date|amount  |balance |?column?
----------------|--------|--------|--------
      2020-06-02| -310.44|46431.95|46742.39
      2020-06-02| -152.48|46742.39|46894.87
      2020-06-02| 1151.25|46894.87|45743.62
      2020-05-29|   -1.25|45743.62|45744.87
      2020-05-29|   -2.00|45744.87|45746.87
      2020-05-29|-1266.30|45746.87|47013.17
      2020-05-29| 3125.00|47013.17|43888.17
      2020-05-28|  158.48|43888.17|43729.69
```

Comment: What if the same `balance - amount` appears twice? I don't think the problem cannot be solved in general, and you need another column that determines the order.

Answer (score 0):

You need a calculated row and order by this row so, you need to use `WINDOW` functions. Try something like this:

```sql
 SELECT id, 
        transaction_date,
        balance,
        amount,
        balance-amount AS row_balance,
        COALESCE(lag(balance-amount, 1) OVER (), 0),
        balance - amount + COALESCE(lag(balance-amount, 1) OVER (), 0) AS last_balance 
    FROM t
ORDER BY 6
```

The `lag(<column>, <lag>) OVER ()` function will get the `column` and do a `lag` on retrieve the information so, you can get the values from the last row inside your current row.

The `OVER ()` is the instruction to apply the window function. As you don't need to group the window or order the information inside the window, you don't need more instructions here.

Only if you want to list the balance separated by user (for example), In this case you can see more details [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

This will create a lag, beginning from value `0` and creating the `balance-amount` for every line with a lag of 1 line.

Here is the PostgreSQL [fiddle](http://create%20table%20t(id%20serial,%20transaction_date%20date,amount%20numeric,%20balance%20numeric);%20insert%20into%20t%20(transaction_date,%20amount,balance)%20values%20('2020-06-02',-310.44,46431.95),%20('2020-05-29',%20%20-1.25,%20%2045743.62),%20('2020-06-02',%20%20-152.48,%20%20%20%2046742.39),%20('2020-05-29',%20%20-2.00,%20%2045744.87),%20('2020-05-29',%20%203125.00,%20%20%20%2047013.17),%20('2020-06-02',%20%201151.25,%20%20%20%2046894.87),%20('2020-05-29',%20%20-1266.30,%20%20%2045746.87),%20('2020-05-28',%20%20158.48,%2043888.17);) solved with your example.